# Befriending a class

Tags: c++, friend

I am trying to befriend a class in order for it to be able to reach a private constructor of it.

In some_file.h

```
class B;    

namespace some_name {
class A {
  public:
    A() {}
  private:
    A (int x) {}
    friend class ::B;
};
}
```

In other_file.h

```
#include "some_file"

namespace {
class B {
  protected:
    A* get_a(int x) { return new A(x); }
};   
}
```

When compiling this code, I get -
error: 'some_name::A::A(int)' is private.

I now, it is private, this is why I befriended B.
What am I doing wrong here?
Can't you befriend your constructor?
Is there a namespace issue?

Thanks

Comment: To befriend other classes, simply don a top hat, have a walking cane which you are practised in twirling, and some nice shoes with the fresh smell of leather.  "There goes the man with the twinkle in his eye!" people will comment, opening the door to new opportunities with new classes.

Answer (score 9):

Doing this:

```
namespace {
class B {
  protected:
    A* get_a(int x) { return new A(x) };
}   
}
```

You're not putting `B` in the root (global) namespace but in an anonymous one.

So `B` can't be reached by `::B`.

If you want `B` to be in the root (global) namespace, just don't enclose it with `namespace` at all. This should do the trick.

Comment: ok, but if I have no control over the location of B and it has to be  an anonymous namespace, how can I still make it work?

Comment: @izex: The role of this anonymous namespace is precisely to forbid references to this type outside of the anonymous namespace. Unless you move `A` declaration into the same anonymous namespace there is no way.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: @izex: I can see at your profile that you didn't accept any answer to your questions yet. If an answer satisfies your needs, don't forget to accept it. And welcome to SO !

Comment: that's wrong. The "anonymous namespace" effect here is completely defeated by the fact it's in a header. Any implementation file that #includes the header statically links the contents of that namespace to itself, thus gaining the anonymous namespace's contents. That is to say, you _can_ access `B`, just say `B` and not `::B`.

Answer (score 1):

You only forward declared and friended a class B in the global namespace. Not a class B in a namespace whatever. You need to fully qualify the name of B.

Edit: Thanks ereOn.
I made a slight mistake. It's true that the reason that you've got a problem is because you've mis-declared and mis-referred-to B, but my original statement wasn't quite true. You need to take B out of the anonymous namespace - it's pointless being in a header anyway.

Comment: The name of `B` was already fully qualified (`::B`) but I guess the OP just meant that an empty namespace was resulting to the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you refer to `B` as `::B` instead of `B`. Meaning, you're telling the compiler that `B` is a global name, but in fact it isn't: it's inside an anonymous namespace. You don't have to remove the anonymous namespace, it's just that it may not do what you expect it to do. Because the anonymous namespace is in a header it means what's inside that namespace is linked statically to any implementation file that includes the header. That's not very useful, because you hide nothing. You might as well remove that anonymous namespace.

Answer (score 0):

> Can't you befriend your constructor?

You can as shown below

```
struct B{
    B();
    void f();
};

struct A{
    friend B::B();
private:
    A(){}
};

B::B(){A a;}       // fine

void B::f(){A a;}  // error

int main(){
}
```